# iPhone App Testing: How do I get a clean install?

Tags: ios

When testing an iPhone app I am developing there are certain steps I can take to induce an error which would for example cause the app to crash on loading or at some other point consistently even if I were to kill the app and load it up again.

I would assume that in order to reset this internal inconstancy of state that is causing the crashing that I could simply reinstall the app. However, the problem will persist after reinstall and can only be resolved by installing a more recent build.

I can only assume that some app data is being retained and reused even though it is being deleted and reinstalled (from IPA).

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? E.g. doing some kind of 'clean install'?

Edit: If I reinstall AND restart my phone then the problem is solved. Does this point to any issues with the app code in particular?

Comment: Does this happen with any version of your app or just one particular version?

Comment: Well its a bug with a particular version that is causing the crashing in the first place. It's not always been the case that a reinstall + restart is required to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the source of your persistent data, you can always go to the root iPhone Simulator folder and delete the application data there. That way you don't have to remove everything from your simulator.

The folder is hidden, so you may need to unhide your folders to see it.

/Users/yourName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator

The next time you run your app, it will be a clean install.

Answer (score 4):

In order to remove any stored data about an app in the iOS Simulator, follow these steps:

1) Open the Simulator (it doesn't matter which app you open, as long as the Simulator is open) 

2) Click on "iOS Simulator" on the top-left of the screen.

3) Press "Reset Content and Settings..." (**WARNING**: This will delete everything on the iOS Simulator, including installed applications, settings, and stored data).

4) Re-install the app in the iOS Simulator, and this time it should be a clean installation.